# OrderBy to sort a 2D array in .NET C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

Whats wrong with this code?

I'm using `System.Linq`

```
int[,] array = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 4, 2 },
                               { 4, 5, 1 },
                               { 7, 3, 8 } 
                             };

int[,] sortedByFirst = array.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
int[,] sortedBySecond = array.OrderBy(x => x[1]);
int[,] sortedByThird = array.OrderBy(x => x[2]);
```

Error:

> Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Make sure you are using `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: Array implements non generic `IEnumerable`, so you need to cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` for using `OrderedBy`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Which wouldn't work because the `IEnumerable` returns all the `int` values rather than subarrays.  And you cannot just cast to `IEnumerable<T>` you'd have to use `Cast<int>()`.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I know that it returns all elements and this doesn't solve his problem by end. It only helps him to resolve a compile errors.

Answer (score 2):

2D Arrays don't work well with LINQ. What do you expect `OrderBy` to receive and sort, even if it were implemented on an n-dimensional array?

Much better to work with `List`.

```
var src = new List<int[]> { new[] { 1, 4, 2 },
                  new[] { 4, 5, 1 },
                  new[] { 7, 3, 8 } 
                };

var sortedByFirst = src.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToList();
var sortedBySecond = src.OrderBy(x => x[1]).ToList();
var sortedByThird = src.OrderBy(x => x[2]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

2D Arrays don't work with OrderBy. Feel free to try this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; ++i)
                    {
                        for (int j = i; j < array.GetLength(0); ++j)
                        {
                           // for first column

                           int a = array[i,0]; // this way you can choose column whatever you want
                            int b = array[j,0];

                            if (a < b) 
                            {

                                for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); ++x)
                                {
                                    string temp = array[i, x];
                                    array[i, x] = array[j, x];
                                    array[j, x] = temp;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is ambiguity about what you're trying to achieve.  Are you looking to keep the "grid rows" in sync with each other when you sort by one of the "columns"?  Or are you expecting to just have the values from a single "column" returned in order, separately from the other "columns"?

If it's the first, then I'd recommend following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232395/how-do-i-sort-a-two-dimensional-array-in-c) example from another question similar to this one, and leverage the `DataTable` class to keep your rows from getting mixed up.

If it's the second, then you can just order the column via `array[0].OrderBy(x=>x);`

btw, I think with your code...

```
        int[,] ordered = array.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToArray();
```

...that you were looking to use the `int[][]` type array, not the `int[,]` type array.  The `OrderBy` exists for the other one, but it doesn't do what you're expecting I don't think.  I've just tried it and I can't figure out what it's even doing.

Hope this helps!